# Jest mock module resolve with variable value

Tags: reactjs, testing, promise, jestjs

Assuming I have a module which returns a promise.
I want to mock different outcomes of this promise to test the function where this module is part of. I mock the module like this:

```
jest.mock('../request', () => {
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve({
            response: { ok: true }
        });
    });
});
```

My first test is running

```
test("The function resolves", () => {
  const initialState = { apiData: getState("postData", {}, "ready", "POST") };
  const store: any = mockStore(initialState);
  return expect(
    performApiRequest("postData/", {}, { data: "json" })(dispatch, () =>
      store.getState()
    )
  ).resolves.toBeUndefined();
});
```

The problem is now with testing an other function where the value that resolves is supposed to be different, for instance {response: { ok: false } }.

I already tried different things. First wrapping the mock in a function and give the response as an argument. --> fails for mocks can't take out of scope variables.

I tried to call jest.doMock within the test but this does not trigger the request correctly.

I tried to do

```
const mockResponse = jest.fn();
jest.mock("../request", () => {
  return () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return resolve({
        mockResponse
      });
    });
});
```

And then call mockResponse.mockReturnValueOnce(value).

No success yet. Anybody sees a way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer with typescript would be:

```
import request from '../request';

jest.mock("../request", () =>
  jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      response: {
        ok: true
      }
    })
  )
);

test("MyTest", () => {
    (request as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
            response: {
                ok: true
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a default mock function at the top level with `jest.fn`. Once you create the mock you can override the implementation of the function within the test case with [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) or [`mockImplementationOnce`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationoncefn). You can find more information about this in the Jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-docs-en-mock-function-api-mockfnmockimplementationfn-or-mockimplementationonce-docs-en-mock-function-api-mockfnmockimplementationoncefn).

```
import request from '../request';

jest.mock("../request", () =>
  jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      response: {
        ok: true
      }
    })
  )
);

test("MyTest", () => {
  request.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      response: {
        ok: false
      }
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Problem with this implementation is that my typescript does not seem to like that.
mockImplementationOnce does not exist on request. So I need to find a workaround for that.